# Data returned from controller is not displayed in thymeleaf page

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf for the first time.I was trying to display the details returned from controller class.Nothing is getting displayed in the front end.I am pasting my code below.Please help.

Controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getNews", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getNews(Model model) {
      try {
        model.addAttribute("ExampleBeans", newsService.getNews());
        System.out.println(" Test" + model.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return "news";
 }
```

Response is getting printed correctly in sysout

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
      href="../../css/gtvg.css" th:href="@{/css/gtvg.css}" />
<title>News</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>

<tbody>
 <p th:text="${ExampleBeans.size()}"> </p>
 <tr th:each="ExampleBean : ${ExampleBeans}">
    <td>inside loop</td>
    <td th:text="${ExampleBean.author}"> </td>
    <td th:text="${ExampleBean.title}"> </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Only inside loop is getting printed when i am try to load url from chrome.

Bean Class

```
public class ExampleBean {
private Long id;

private String author;

private String title;

//getter and setters
```

Thymeleaf Dependency added

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: What is the type of `ExampleBeans`? Presumably it is a `List<SomeClass>`. Show the code of `SomeClass`.

Comment: Code seems to be correct. Do have all required dependencies? Here's a [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-iteration) which explains exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: I have added bean class also now.ExampleBeans is List<ExampleBean>. @Andreas

Comment: I have added thymeleaf dependency and webservice dependency in pom.xml. Do i need to add any more dependencies? @MartinBG

Comment: You'll need `thymeleaf-spring5` too. Have you checked the tutorial I gave link to?

Comment: ya i checked the link you shared. But,in that they where using spring 5 instead of springboot i think.However,I tried adding that dependency still its not working

Comment: If you do a "View Source" in the web browser, does the `<p>` and the two `<td>` elements still have the `th:text` attributes? If yes, then it seems that Thymeleaf is not processing the HTML file.